# Entity Framework 7 Foreign Key Column Name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a MasterUserApprovalOfficial entity with two foreign keys, MasterUserId and SoftwareSystemId. EF 7 is smart enough to figure out that these two properties are foreign keys.Here is my MasterUserApprovalOfficial class

```
public class MasterUserApprovalOfficial
{
    public int MasterUserApprovalOfficialId { get; set; }

    public int MasterUserId { get; set; }

    public MasterUser MasterUser { get; set; }

    public int SofwareSystemId { get; set; }

    public SoftwareSystem SoftwareSystem { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public MasterUserApprovalOfficial()
    {
        CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

If I look at the table that was created the MasterUserId column was created and named as expected, the SoftwareSystemId column however is created as `SoftwareSystemSoftwareSystemId` (The name of the class appended to the name of the primary key)

[image]

Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public int SofwareSystemId { get; set; }
```

read that property again. there's a t missing :)

the second answer is also right, you don't need properties for the foreign key. A member of the class is enough

Comment: Nice catch, it's weird it changes the name of the foreign key then

Comment: It is indeed, seems like a weird behavior of the EF. The only explanation i have for this is that EF is 'smart' and does not want to confuse the user when it generates columns.

Comment: Thank you, totally missed it! Reading, the real, an art I guess!

Comment: You're welcome. Can you tell us if the foreign key is now named as it should? would be interesting to know :)

Comment: Yes it is now named as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ForeignKey` and `Column` attributes to fix this:

```
[ForeignKey("SoftwareSystem"),Column("SoftwareSystemId")]
public int SoftwareSystemId { get; set; }
```

By default the foreign key will be added with "Id" behind it, but because you already have a property with that name (and EF doesn't recognize it's the foreignkey apparantly) it gets changed into `SoftwareSystemSoftwareSystemId`.